# Ordering the contents of a list in r

Tags: r

[image]
I used the following code to order the data ( seen in the picture) in descending order. The code does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
     Unlisted_Ireland_data=unlist(Ireland_data)
     Unlisted_Ireland_data
     sorted=Unlisted_Ireland_data[order(Unlisted_Ireland_data)]
     usingsort=sort(Unlisted_Ireland_data)
     usingsort
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Maybe try: `sort(Unlisted_Ireland_data)` ?

Comment: I tried sort(Unlisted_Ireland_data), it gives the wrong output .Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output. I am guessing your numbers are strings, so all getting sorted alphabetically.

Comment: If the numbers are strings or if there's a mix of character strings and numbers, try `stringr::str_sort(., numeric = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

The data in `usingsort` are indeed sorted - just not the way you want them to be. `Unlisted_Ireland_data` is a vector of type `character` and is sorted as such. `"102.18"` comes before `"41.66"` as `"1"` comes before `"4"`.

You probably expected the data to be ordered as numbers but for that you will have to convert the vector to `numeric` fist.

Try

```
expl1 <- c("100.0", "20", "3")
sort(expl1)

expl2 <- as.numeric(expl1)
sort(expl2)

typeof(expl1)
typeof(expl2)
```

In `Unlisted_Ireland_data` there is this one entry "Ireland" which will prohibit changing this vector with `as.numeric`. Check if there are more entries that cannot be changed into a value and remove all of them before changing to `numeric`.